# how to programatically run a task when a logout occurs in mac

Tags: macos, shell, logout

I am trying to run a shell command when Logout Event occurs in Mac

```
 logoutNotificationCenter.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.logOut),name:NSWorkspace.willPowerOffNotification, object: nil)
```

inside logout I am using to run a shell command

```
func shell(path:String,commandargs: [String]) -> Bool
    {
        var ret : Bool = false
        
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = path
        task.arguments = commandargs
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        
        if !task.isRunning {
            let status = task.terminationStatus
            if status == 0 {
                ret = true
            } else {
                ret = false
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
```

Though my notification is triggered by shell is not being run , even before that my system is shutting down. Is there a way I can halt logout until my shell command is executed.

Comment: Return [`terminateLater`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/terminatereply/terminatelater) in the [`applicationShouldTerminate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428642-applicationshouldterminate) and then call [`reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428594-reply) when your task finishes.

Comment: Thank you , I tried this after returning terminate later my shell code is getting executed but even before it returns value my system is logging out.  I followed this https://davidehlen.dev/posts/executing-work-before-termination/.  Even before returning terminate later I am call my code under  DispatchQueue.main.async, so that terminate will wait and my code executes asynchronously

Comment: I'm not sure (based on your comment) that it helped. Does it work for you as expected?

Comment: You can add in answer. Some extent it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question again and the problem is that the [`applicationShouldTerminate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428642-applicationshouldterminate) is called **before** the `NSWorkspace.willPowerOffNotification` is sent. Which means that you don't know what's going on.

Then I realized that we've got the [`kAEQuitReason`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kaequitreason). Was curious if it still works and it does. Example below. Modify it in a way that fits your needs.

```swift
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow!
    
    private var logoutTaskLaunched = false
    
    private func launchLogoutTask() {
        assert(!logoutTaskLaunched, "Logout task was already launched")
        
        let task = Process()
        task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/sleep")
        task.arguments = ["5"]
        task.terminationHandler = { task in
            if task.terminationStatus == 0 {
                print("Logout task - success")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    NSApp.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: true)
                }
            } else {
                print("Logout task - failed")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    NSApp.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: false)
                    self?.logoutTaskLaunched = false
                }
            }
        }
        do {
            try task.run()
            logoutTaskLaunched = true
            print("Logout task - Sleeping for 5s")
        }
        catch {
            print("Logout task - failed to launch task: \(error)")
            NSApp.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: false)
        }
    }
    
    func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
        let reason = NSAppleEventManager.shared()
            .currentAppleEvent?
            .attributeDescriptor(forKeyword: kAEQuitReason)
        
        switch reason?.enumCodeValue {
        case kAELogOut, kAEReallyLogOut:
            print("Logout")
            if !logoutTaskLaunched {
                launchLogoutTask()
            }
            return .terminateLater
            
        case kAERestart, kAEShowRestartDialog:
            print("Restart")
            return .terminateNow
            
        case kAEShutDown, kAEShowShutdownDialog:
            print("Shutdown")
            return .terminateNow
            
        case 0:
            // `enumCodeValue` docs:
            //
            //    The contents of the descriptor, as an enumeration type,
            //    or 0 if an error occurs.
            print("We don't know")
            return .terminateNow
            
        default:
            print("Cmd-Q, Quit menu item, ...")
            return .terminateNow
        }
    }
}
```